# How to kill a unix process by grabbing its PID and not using awk?

Tags: android

Killing a process can be done by grabbing the process pid and awk:

```
 kill $(ps aux | grep '[m]yprocess' | awk '{print $2}')
```

How can I achieve the exact same thing without using awk, pkill or anything else not available in Android's shell?

Comment: You could use `pkill <process name>`

Comment: `pgrep` should be available. `kill $(pgrep myprocess)`

Comment: no pgrep.. only ps which gives me the full line

Comment: In fact it's only lately that android even has a grep.  If you are running this from application code, you may want to do the identifying in java, and then kill the pid once you know it.

Comment: Toolbox tools are here: https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/tree/master/toolbox still trying to find sources of the shell interpreter itself for builtins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most of the newer *nix systems you have `pkill` available. So just use:

```
pkill -f myprocess
```

to kill a process by name. (Use `killall` on OSX)

In absence of `pkill` you can do:

```
read s _ < <(ps ax | grep '[m]yprocess') && kill "$s"
```

OR if `BASH` isn't available then use:

```
ps ax | grep '[m]yprocess' | while read s _; do kill "$s"; done
```

Comment: Can't use pkill or killall. I want to kill a process in android so only kill pid

Comment: maybe add a tag such as "android"

Comment: @user3184086: Do you not have `pgrep` OR `pkill` or `awk` available there?

Comment: no pgrep, no pkill, no awk, no perl and no python :/

Comment: This is not a typical unix userspace, it's android's primitive "toolbox" shell & tools.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I understand but I believe as long as Bash is there `read` command should work.

Comment: cut is not available too, I googled it hard before asking. Read seems to be available but your cmd is not working, I'll check how it works

Comment: @user3184086: See what output you get by running `read s _ < <(ps ax | grep '[m]yprocess') && echo "$s"` command.

Comment: Or else just show output of `ps ax | grep '[m]yprocess'` command

Comment: @anubhava - Android does not ship bash, it has it's own mini-shell, though some people who root-hack their devices do add it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: In that case I think question wasn't framed correctly. Initially it just had `BASH` tag then OP added `android` though still `BASH` tag remains.

Comment: I have provided a `kill` command that would run without BASH also.

Answer (score 1):

use `cut -cn1-n2` to cut everything but chars from n1 to n2 in place of `awk` call. Find the right columns by looking at the result of `ps aux` and counting char positions for the field `PID`.

Comment: no cut either, this is not a typical unix but rather android's minimal "toolbox" shell & tools